# AWS Beanstalk for .NET application with custom AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use AWS Beanstalk to implement the following:

- Create a "baseline" AMI template which has all the "supporting" sofware which my application needs.
- Use this template as the base image for a .NET MVC Beanstalk applications.

First I got a "Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base-2019.10.09" image from Community AMI library and created an EC2 instance from is. I then went ahead and installed all the needed software, stopped the instance and created a launch template from it. Then I tried various ways to bootstrap a simple sample .NET MVC application with the AMI of the launch template which I have just created. Could not get this work, was getting some cryptic post command errors all over the place.

I then went back to the Community AMI library and searched for another baseline to use. I found the "aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2019.08.16.x86_64-WindowsServer2012R2Core-V2-hvm-201908232334" base image. I created a EC2 instance from this, stopped it and created the launch template. I was finally successful in starting my sample .NET MVC app using this baseline template. At this point, I thought, let me RDP into the EC2 instance (the source of the launch template) and install all the needed software. When I did this, this looks like it is some stripped down version of windows because only one windows opened and its the command prompt (there is no explorer.exe).

My question is:

- Is my approach correct for something like this?
- Should I just try to install all the software thats needed as part of the deployment? I think this might be possible, but it would be a lot of pain ...
- How do I know which AMI baselines I can use with elasticbeanstalk? I cant find any documentation about that these images were build for (other then the image name)
- What are the "NET Beanstalk Cfn Container" and ".NET Beanstalk HostManager" images?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing this statement applies:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html

Note:
AMIs that aren't managed by Elastic Beanstalk aren't supported for Windows Server-based Elastic Beanstalk platforms.

Probably why the EB managed AMI "aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2019.08.16.x86_64-WindowsServer2012R2Core-V2-hvm-201908232334" worked but the community AMI didn't. Assume EB requires a bunch of software installed that isn't present in non-EB managed AMIs.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.